# Open a url-path in angular app clicked from other web

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-bootstrap

In our application we are sending user account activation link to the users via email. On clicking the url, we want to open the url in the angular application. But it is opening the root component of application.

useHash : true is also not helping.

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',useHash : true, })],
```

Is there any configuration available in angular, which can help us to open the url directly?

OR

Can we access value of the url entered in browser address bar in app-component of angular?

Comment: Show the rooting for that component and what your link looks like

Answer (score 0):

thats mean u have a mistake in ur route 
try to check ur component route like this :

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
{ path: 'ResetPassword', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
```